# No AssemblyInfo.cs file when generating a project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to make a simple CLI project with C# and wanted to make a logger for it. I settled on using Log4Net. I was using [this guide](https://stackify.com/log4net-guide-dotnet-logging/) to set it up. On step 3, it recommends we add

```bash
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config")]
```

in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` to tell Log4Net where to load its configuration from.

I tried to follow it and went to Visual Studio to add that to the AssemblyInfo.cs but I was unable to find it. In a screenshot shared by the writer of the guide which can be viewed [here](https://stackify.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/log4net-assemblyinfo-10115.png), it shows that their project has a Properties folder that contains an `AssemblyInfo.cs` file which mine doesn't(Screenshot:

[image: Old Project]

).

I made another project to see if something was wrong with the way the CLI project was created but I still got a project without an `AssemblyInfo.cs`.

Googling the issue I see that I can go to the project properties page and click the assembly information button and have it regenerated but that is also missing for me in both projects.
[image: New Project]

[image: Old project with no assembly info btn]

[image: New project with no assembly info btn]

Any idea why and how I may fix this? Or maybe a way to use Log4Net without an `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add an `AssemblyInfo.cs` file yourself - or call it something else entirely, e.g. `Log4NetAssemblyAttributes`. The name of the file is irrelevant. A file with the attributes from the project file is generated automatically as part of the build in .NET Core, rather than being included as a regular source file in the project template, but you can place an `[assembly:xyz]` attribute in any source file you like.

Comment: I just made a .net forms app that was generated with an `AssemblyInfo.cs` file. Does it have anything to do with the type of project being created?

Comment: @Satindar31: Yes. If you use the old Framework-style project, I believe you'll still get an AssemblyInfo.cs generated in the project. If you use the newer SDK-style project (which is *much* cleaner IMO) then you won't. But that still doesn't stop you from adding assembly-level attributes.